# Create a button programmatically and set a background image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

When I try creating a button and setting a background image in Swift:

```
let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
    button.setImage(IMAGE, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

I always get an error: "**Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'UIImage'**".

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare `IMAGE`?

Comment: How are you creating the image? May need to unwrap it IMAGE!

Comment: `IMAGE` should look like `UIImage(named: "name")`

Comment: Thank you this works! I only said:
"button.setImage("CircleTap", forState: UIControlState.Normal)"
but now it works perfectly

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Your code should look like below

```
let image = UIImage(named: "name") as UIImage?
let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: I think it should actually be `as? UIImage`  Your version will crash if `imageNamed:` returns nil.

Comment: Well that's your fault if its nil but you can add the ? but then you will have to also be aware of that when `setImage`. I guess it depends how defensive you want to get and since you control the local asset there should be no surprise with a unit test or two

Comment: What about for circles images?

Comment: Try adding the ? `as UIImage?`

Comment: change button type to Custom if you don't want to see a blue button button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

Comment: I don't think you can use "UIButton.buttonWithType" in Swift2

Comment: This is from swift 1. If Swift 2 is different then we need to edit the answer to include 2.0 syntax

Comment: Did `UIImage(...)` ever return `Any?`? Or why do you convert object type to the same type?

Answer (score 28):

Try below:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "ImageName.png") as UIImage
var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
button .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
menuView.addSubview(button)
```

Let me know whether if it works or not?

Comment: you should set buttonWithType to UIButtonType.Custom, not to System until the image shows

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 5** version of accepted answer:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name")
let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(function), for: .touchUpInside)

//button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

where of course

```
@objc func function() {...}
```

The image is aligned to center by default. You can change this by setting button's imageEdgeInsets, like this:

```
// In this case image is 40 wide and aligned to the left
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: button.frame.width - 45)
```

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 3 Version** of Alex Reynolds' Answer

```
let image = UIImage(named: "name") as UIImage?
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("btnTouched:"), for:.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 6):

> Create Button and add image as its background swift 4

```
     let img = UIImage(named: "imgname")
     let myButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
     myButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 45)
     myButton.setImage(img, for: .normal)
     myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
     self.view.addSubview(myButton)
```

Comment: Correction:line 4] button.setImage(image, for: .normal)

Answer (score 5):

You need check for image is not nil before assign it to button.

Example:

```
let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
if let image  = UIImage(named: "imagename.png") {
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
}

button.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: I would think I would want the app to crash if the image is not in the project.  so why check?

Comment: Becuase then the app wouldn't crash and could ship with a missing image

Answer (score 4):

```
let btnRight=UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
btnRight.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)
btnRight.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "menu.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnRight.setTitle("Right", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnRight.tintColor=UIColor.blackColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can create a beautiful button with a bezel and rounded edges:

```
loginButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x + (self.view.bounds.width * 0.325), self.view.bounds.origin.y + (self.view.bounds.height * 0.8), self.view.bounds.origin.x + (self.view.bounds.width * 0.35), self.view.bounds.origin.y + (self.view.bounds.height * 0.05)))
loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0
loginButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
loginButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 24.0/100, green: 116.0/255, blue: 205.0/205, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

To set background we can no longer use `forState`, so we have to use `for` to set the `UIControlState`:

```
let zoomInImage = UIImage(named: "Icon - plus") as UIImage?
let zoomInButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10), y: 10, width: 45, height: 45))
zoomInButton.setBackgroundImage(zoomInImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
zoomInButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.mapZoomInAction), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(zoomInButton)
```

Comment: I use this code to put zoom button on google map. use the above code for set background image. It is not same as earlier.

Comment: How is it different from the other answers though?

Comment: To set background now we cant use forState now we have to use "for" to set the UIControlState

Answer (score 2):

Update to **Swift 3**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "name")
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAbsRetClicked(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift: Ui Button create programmatically

```
let myButton = UIButton()

myButton.titleLabel!.frame = CGRectMake(15, 54, 300, 500)

myButton.titleLabel!.text = "Button Label"

myButton.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

myButton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center

myButton.addTarget(self,action:"Action:",forControlEvents:UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(myButton)
```